# Chatter Feed Item Actions

Tags: chatter, feeditem

Need to add Feed Item Actions..i tried adding quick actions.

But is it possible to have Feed item action as Escalate to Case? as like this?
[image]

We can add in the More items.

I tried adding Quick actions as in documentation and changing feed item layout..not working.

I have added to the publisher layout and i am okay to see New COntact and New lead here...[image]
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you want the action "Escalate to case" to do?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there are two actions that can performed from the context of a Feed Item.  One is "Escalate to Case", which you mentioned in your question.  The other is "Create New Task", which allows you to create a task off of a feed item.

You can add the "Create New Task" action to feed items by adding it to the Feed Item Layout.

More information about this feed item action and how to set it up in the Spring '15 Release Notes (http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_chatter_feeds_tasks_enable.htm).

If you need other quick actions (e.g. accounts, contacts, etc.), unfortunately they are currently not addable to Feed Item Layouts, but you can add them to the Publisher Layout as you mentioned above.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your actions to the publisher layout.

Comment: When you add in Publisher Layouts - it is visible in More as like i have added New Contact or New lead..i wanted to add this action at question level.